# Configure iisexpress to run mvc project anonymously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2013

There seems to be a lot of articles how to solve the 401.2 unauthorized, but all seem to hint to turn the Windows Authentication back on.

What I need is to run the MVC app on http anonymously in context of SharePoint provider hosted applciation on a developer machine. I understand that w/o windows auth i dont get debugging, but that's ok. I am doing a POC right now.

I changed the csproj file of the mvc csproj to output iisexpress settings in a applicationhost.config file via <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>true</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>

Then, i have configured the anonymous authentication.

```
    <authentication>

            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />

            <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />

            <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />

            <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />

            <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
            </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>

            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
                <providers>
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                </providers>
            </windowsAuthentication>

    </authentication>
```

I am still getting the following
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any authentication then try following configuration. I disabled basic authentication and removed user tag from anonymous authentication.

```
<authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
        </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <add value="Negotiate" />
                <add value="NTLM" />
            </providers>
        </windowsAuthentication>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Your configuration would work. I did solve the issue. I had to make sure that the <deny users="?" /> is removed.  It was there from the default template.  I missed it.  Thanks.